# rails 3 - code shared between multiple controllers - where to put it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a piece of code that is needed in 2 of my controllers, but not all of them. Where does this method belong?
I have read about helpers, but those seem to be for view-related code. Someone proposed the lib-folder, but that seems 'too far away' from the controller logic, i don't need it in views or models.
Has someone experience with that sort of problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three options, the easiest (though, the most unclean) is the application controller. The other two options are a shared parent controller

```
class FooController < FooBarParentController
   # code here  
end

class BarController < FooBarParentController
   # code here  
end
```

Usage depends on how related these controllers are.

The final solution is a module

```
module FooBarModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # class level code
    # before_filter ....
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # all class methods here
  end

  # instance methods here
end
```

This is where the shared code required is for a handful of ad-hoc controllers, or if you are already using the inheritance above and this code doesn't quite fit into this subset (thus attempting to emulate multiple inheritance).

Comment: thanks for this helpful answer! the last solution seems to me the most flexible, so i think i will try this one. could you explain a little where i should put this code (in a module in the lib-folder?)

Comment: I'd personally put it in the controllers folder.

Comment: If it pertains specifically to this application, put it under the app folder (perhaps in a 'modules' subdirectory). The lib folder is more for general purpose utilities that aren't app specific.

Comment: thanks very much, that really helped me. i ended up putting the file with the FooBarModule in the controllers-folder, because as i said it is only controller-related. i could then just 'include FooBarModule' in my controllers (i didn't even need to require it first, as i had thought). Works like a charm!